# Sql syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to highlight sql syntax on Visual Studio 2022? An extension or a configuration in VS option?
See a raw query with flat color is a little bit frustrating (it is already frustrating to use a raw query). Here an example:

[image: raw query example]

Comment: If you use a [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) you can at least spread the query text out over several lines to make it easier to read.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the comment, but I already knew this. My question is different.

Comment: I expect you've already found that there *was* an extension for older VS versions that did what you're after. You could switch to using stored procedures so that the SQL doesn't appear in the code, or you could save the query in a file with an extension of ".sql", which VS will happily open and colour for you. I think the latter could be a bit tedious unless the queries are large. Just some suggestions....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the [SQL Tools Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Mojtabakaviani.SqlTools)? It looks to do what you want.

Comment: Wonderful! I used this extension on vs2019 but did'nt find it on vs2022. They've released it! Thanks